# Windows Store Game: DirectX for game and XAML for rich UI

Tags: performance, xaml, windows-8, directx, windows-store-apps

Is it ok to use XAML for building vector (scalable) rich UI (with forms containing buttons, listboxes etc) in DirectX Windows Store game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use XAML and DirectX together in a Windows Store app.  Here is an article explaining [DirectX and XAML interop](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/hh825871.aspx) and [another article from the Windows 8 app developer blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2012/03/15/combining-xaml-and-directx.aspx).

In summary, your options are:

1. You can use the [SurfaceImageSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.surfaceimagesource.aspx) XAML type to add areas of DirectX content to a Metro style XAML app.
2. You can use [VirtualSurfaceImageSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.media.imaging.virtualsurfaceimagesource.aspx) for large-scale DirectX content + XAML UI.
3. You can use [SwapChainBackgroundPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.swapchainbackgroundpanel.aspx) for DirectX with a XAML overlay.

Comment: Thank you Jennifer for really fast answer, but I'm not sure about perfomance. Doesn't using complex nested UI tree strongly impact it?

Comment: The controls were designed with performance in mind.  I would suggest reading that interop article to understand the concepts, and then prototyping something to get a sense for performance.